# php artisan is not working in lavavel5.4 in XAMPP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to run **PHP ARTISAN** commands in *cmd*. I am geting this error in *CMD*

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Attribute [resouce] does not exist.
```

Anything I write with php artisan gives me this error like:

```
php artisan make:model testModel
php artisan route:list
```

Complete error message is:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel5.4>php artisan make:mode TestModel
[InvalidArgumentException]
Attribute [resouce] does not exist.
```

It was working fine I just made a change in database directly like changed the ***role*** to ***role_id*** in **user table** after that it stops working.

Comment: Check your route file for a `Route::resouce` call. Note the misspelling.

Comment: ohhh ok i got it. thanks alot brother